# Add a click event that happens after inline click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Using jQuery, I want to add a click event to a search button that happens after the event that is already tied to that button in the HTML (the other click event is in the tag's onclick event, it is NOT added by javascript).

I've tried using `.click(function() {...});` but that event will fire before the inline onclick event already on the button. How can I run my click event after the first one has completed?

Comment: Placing javascript event handlers inline in your HTML is a terrible practice. If possible, you should just bind both handlers with jQuery.click, and control their order that way.

Comment: As a google chrome extension (see tags) whether it's inline or not is not up to me. I'm working around code already in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is grab the inline events when the page loads and evaluate them before your custom click event code.

Something like this:

```
var events = $('#someAnchor').attr('onclick');
$('#someAnchor').removeAttr('onclick');

$('#someAnchor').click(function(){
    eval(events);
    alert("We came second");
})
```

Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkVuP/